# Finder Cover flow alloactes second FIFinderSync

Tags: findersync

Has anyone else seen this problem?

I have a finder extension and have noticed that when I switched the finder display mode to 'cover flow' that a second instance of the FIFinderSync is allocated and then after that calling:

```
[[FIFinderSyncController defaultController] setBadgeIdentifier:overlayID forURL:url];
```

fails to set the badges anymore. I noticed that Dropbox has the same problem.

Is this a bug in the finder?

I am running 10.13.5.

Comment: If you [file a radar](https://bugreport.apple.com/), I will duplicate it.

Comment: I have opened an apple bug report on this now. ID #41469982